# Querying on multiple tables using google apps engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model

I have three tables, 1-Users, 2-Softwares, 3-UserSoftwares.

if suppose, Users table having 6 user records(say U1,U2,...,U6) and Softwares table having 4 different softwares(say S1,S2,S3,S4) and UserSoftwares stores the references if a user requested for given software only.
For example: UserSoftwares(5 records) have only two columns(userid, softwareid) which references others. and the data is:

### U1   S1

### U2   S2

### U2   S3

### U3   S3

### U4   S1

Now I m expecting following results:(if current login user is U2):

---

### S1  Disable

### S2  Enable

### S3  Enable

### S4  Disable

Here, 1st column is softwareid or name and 2nd column is *status* which having only two values(Enable/Disable) based on UserSoftwares table(model). **Note** *status* is not a field of any model(table).
"My Logic is: 
1. loop through each software in softwares model
2. find softwareid with current login userid (U2) in UserSoftwares model: 
    if it found then set status='Enable'
    if not found then set status='Disable'
3. add this status property to software object.
4. repeat this procedure for all softwares. 
"
What should be the query in python google app engine to achieve above result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since GAE's datastore is **not** relational you have to model your *many-to-many* relationship without using *joins*. Here are two methods you can adapt easily to your needs.

## Working example using link model method (UPDATE #1)

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

# Defining models

class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()


class Software(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()


class UserSoftwares(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='users')
    software = db.ReferenceProperty(Software, collection_name='softwares')

# Creating users

u1 = User(name='John Doe')
u2 = User(name='Jane Doe')

# Creating softwares    
sw1 = Software(name='Office 2007')
sw2 = Software(name='Google Chrome')
sw3 = Software(name='Notepad ++')

# Batch saving entities
db.put([u1, u2, sw1, sw2, sw3])

"""
Creating relationship between users and softwares;
in this example John Doe's softwares are 'Office 2007' and
'Notepad++' while Jane Doe only uses 'Google Chrome'.
"""
u1_sw1 = UserSoftwares(user=u1, software=sw1)
u1_sw3 = UserSoftwares(user=u1, software=sw3)
u2_sw2 = UserSoftwares(user=u2, software=sw2)

# Batch saving relationships
db.put([u1_sw1, u1_sw3, u2_sw2])

"""
Selects all softwares.
"""

rs1 = Software.all()

# Print results
print ("SELECT * FROM Software")
for sw in rs1:
    print sw.name

"""
Selects a software given it's name.
"""

rs2 = Software.all().filter("name =", "Notepad ++")

# Print result
print("""SELECT * FROM Software WHERE name = ?""")
print rs2.get().name

"""
Selects all software used by 'John Smith'.
"""

# Get John Doe's key only, no need to fetch the entire entity
user_key = db.Query(User, keys_only=True).filter("name =", "John Doe").get()

# Get John Doe's software list
rs3 = UserSoftwares.all().filter('user', user_key)

# Print results
print ("John Doe's software:")
for item in rs3:
    print item.software.name

"""
Selects all users using the software 'Office 2007'
"""

# Get Google Chrome's key
sw_key = db.Query(Software, keys_only=True).filter("name =", "Google Chrome").get()

# Get Google Chrome's user list
rs4 = UserSoftwares.all().filter('software', sw_key)

# Print results
print ("Google Chrome is currently used by:")
for item in rs4:
    print item.user.name
```

### Link model method (recommended)

You can model a *many-to-many* relationship by representing each table in this way:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db    

class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()


class Software(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()


class UserSoftwares(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='users')
    software = db.ReferenceProperty(Software, collection_name='softwares')
```

As you can see it is quite similiar to the relational's way of thinking.

### Key list method (alternative)

Relationships can also be modelled as *list of keys*:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    softwares = db.ListProperty(db.Key)


class Software(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.TextProperty()

    @property
    def users(self):
        return User.all().filter('softwares', self.key())
```

This approach is more suited for a small number of keys since it uses a ListProperty but is *faster* than than the *link model method* above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am expecting to get all softwares(SELECT * FROM software). Now if current login user is 'U2'. then it check for each software whether is assigned for user 'U2', if it find from UserSoftwares then status='Enable', otherwise status='Disable'. Note status field is not present in any model.

Comment: @Nilesh-T you don't need a status field for getting all software assigned to a specific user, but i'll update my answer with some examples based on the models i gave you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's a nice post with working example.

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking for `join` - there is no joins in GAE. BTW, there is pretty easy to make 2 simple queries (`Softwares` and `UserSoftware`), and calculate all additional data manually

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Modeling Entity Relationships Datastore Article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html), you can model this somewhat like a tradition Many-to-Many relationship in a RDBMS.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Software(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class UserSoftware(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True, collection_name='softwares')
    software = db.ReferenceProperty(Software, required=True, collection_name='users')

# use the models like so:

alice = User(name='alice')
alice.put()

s1 = Software(name='s1')
s1.put()

us = UserSoftware(user=alice,software=s1)
us.put()
```

Hope this helps.